# How do you post a Map to Phoenix using JSON?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new to Elixir 1.3.2 and Phoenix 1.2.1 and i'm trying to post a user object(map) to phoenix after following [this](https://blog.codeship.com/ridiculously-fast-api-authentication-with-phoenix/) tutorial. I'm using postman and the correct url http://localhost:4000/api/users. At first i tried a raw body with a json object but then i got a missing key exception: expected key "user" to be present in params, please send the expected key or adapt your scrub_params/2 call

Then i used the formdata option in postman with a key:"User" and value:"{email: "foo@bar.be", password: "s3cr3t"}". This resulted in the following error response from the elixir API: expected params to be a map, got: `"{email: \"foo@bar.be\", password: \"s3cr3t\"}"`

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? And how you would make sure JSON gets serialized/matched to a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON that you need to send to the server needs to look something like

```
{
  "user": {
    "email": "foo@email.com",
    ...
  }
}
```

Note how there is a user key at the top level. That is what your error meant by

> expected key "user" to be present in params

Comment: The format you suggest isn't working. I get the error: 

expected key "user" to be present in params, please send the expected key or adapt your scrub_params/2 call 

i need to use user:{"email":"foo@email.com","password":"secret"} but then i get:
expected params to be a map, got: `"{\"email\":\"foo@email.com\",\"password\":\"secret\"}"`

Comment: On each request in dev mode, Phoenix tells you what your params are. As an example, I just logged into one of my services, and the console said `Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "...", "_utf8" => "✓", "session" => %{"email" => "foo@email.com", "password" => "[FILTERED]"}}`. In this case, my "session" key is at the top level as I am dealing with a session. Does your parameters list have a "user" key at the top level?

Comment: The console is a phoenix console and not a json body in a http request? I have a user key at the root of my request body

Comment: I forgot my content header! so your answer was correct.